# configuring fish shell prompt inside nix-shell

Tags: shell, fish, nix, nix-shell

I tried following the steps here to configure the prompt: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Fish

Combined with the information here about the location and content of a basic file: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-set-my-prompt

If I understood correctly the content of `fish_prompt.fish` should be:

```
set -l nix_shell_info (
if test -n "$IN_NIX_SHELL"
    echo -n "<nix-shell> "
end
)

function fish_prompt
    set_color $fish_color_cwd
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
    set_color normal
    echo -n -s ' $nix_shell_info ~>'
end
```

After setting it this way the prompt is the same whether in a `nix-shell` or not and the variable `$nix_shell_info` does not get set.

How can I set it so that it works as intended?

Comment: could someone justify why a down-vote was required so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the variable inside the function, otherwise it would always contain the value set when the file was loaded:

```
function fish_prompt
    set -l nix_shell_info (
        if test -n "$IN_NIX_SHELL"
            echo -n "<nix-shell> "
        end
    )

    set_color $fish_color_cwd
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
    set_color normal
    echo -n -s " $nix_shell_info ~>"
end
```

**Edit:** As cole-h pointed out on IRC, you also need to also change the single quotes containing the variable to double quotes or it will not be interpolated.

Comment: Even when using this the variable is not being replaced, see: https://gist.github.com/razvan-flavius-panda/be039cf60faabd419e368e262393263d